# Confusion of static variables in java

Tags: java

How to write a java program making use of static variables such that only an even number of objects of a certain class X can be instantiate.

E.g. Only allowed to create 2 or 4 or 6....(etc.) objects of that class but never 1 or 3 or 5 (etc.)

Comment: How do you plan on making 4 if you can't make 3? Can you only make two at a time? What if the user instantiates two and throws away one?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Exactly what @MCMastery said. You should instead have a factory method that creates pairs of them.

Comment: I'm a beginer of java. I know this is not for me for now.I'm not skilled enough to sort Out this. Actually it was my dare & that's why I spent last night(almost full). Now 7:30am & I thought before sleep I should post this. Because whatever comes(result) from others/experts have must help me today or tomorrow. Thanks to u !!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write this an "instance" version of the question as *global state* should be avoided.

```
package thing; // Use packages.
public class Thing {
    // Hide this constructor.
    /* pp */ Thing() {
    }
}

package thing;
// We need this because single return value.
// Alternatively, you could have a pair of Consumers
//   or a BiConsumer (which apparently is a thing,
//   notably Map.forEach and Collector.accumulator).
public interface ThingPair {
    Thing a();
    Thing b();
} 

package thing;
public class Things {
    // Return a pair of things at once.
    public ThingPair makePair() {
        Thing a = new Thing();
        Thing b = new Thing();
        return new ThingPair() {
            public Thing a() { return a; }
            public Thing b() { return b; }
        }
    }
}
```